# Removing the cancel button in ASWebAuthenticationSession WebView

Tags: ios, aswebauthenticationsession, swizzle

I am using a `ASWebAuthenticationSession` and want to remove the `cancel` nav bar button so the user cant close the window (mandatory verification needed to use the app)

I cant find a way to achieve this because the `ASWebAuthenticationSession` webview is hidden from us so we cant customise it.

Is there some way to swizzle to remove the left bar button item? my knowledge here is thin, but i cant see any other way of hiding a bar button item on a view we cant access

Thanks for any help or advice here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide `Cancel` button because the screen is defined by Apple framework. Moreover, it's shown by another process so you cannot go through the UI to make it hidden by your own.